# Moving average on DATEDIFF with gaps

Tags: mysql, moving-average

I need to build a time-series with a moving average, with a window size of 6 months, *and* fill in gaps where there's no data.

I have a table with content like this

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|       date_1        |       date_2        |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2018-06-22 06:41:25 | 2018-06-22 07:22:33 |
| 2018-06-22 05:43:23 | 2018-06-24 06:20:23 |
| 2018-06-21 08:56:37 | 2018-06-21 08:56:42 |
| 2018-06-20 09:24:11 | 2018-06-22 08:19:24 |
| 2018-06-20 06:40:23 | 2018-06-20 06:40:28 |
| 2018-06-19 13:37:23 | 2018-06-20 11:06:41 |
| 2018-06-19 09:15:18 | 2018-06-19 09:22:32 |
| 2018-06-19 06:23:19 | 2018-06-19 06:23:23 |
| 2018-06-18 13:54:05 | 2018-06-25 12:14:02 |
| 2018-06-18 09:28:24 | 2018-06-19 08:09:01 |
| ...                 | ...                 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

So the result would end up looking something like this

```
+------------+------+
|    date    | diff |
+------------+------+
| 2018-06-19 |    2 |
| 2018-06-20 |    3 |
| 2018-06-21 |    2 |
+------------+------+
```

Any pointers?

I've created a table with all dates from -5 years to +5 years, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to build the JOIN and AVG

Comment: How exactly is your "diff" calculated? In general this question is lacking some sort of basic algorithm that would describe how you wish to arrive at the expected result

Comment: I'm using DATEDIFF. `DATEDIFF(date_1, date_2)`. Sorry about the missing information, but that's what I need help with

Comment: I'm not asking you to provide code for it, if you don't know it. My point is, it will be easier for us to create a code when we know how we can consinstently arrive at the desired result - which at least to me  wasn't clear from the initial question. /// **So, if i get it right, basically you want to compare all unqiue values and compare the average for each unqiue value right?** - eg. `DATEDIFF(AVG(date_1), AVG(date_2))` *(not actual code, just simplified pseudo code, as to how would you describe each row)*

Comment: Not sure I follow you here. 
I would like to build a complete set of dates between `NOW - 6 months` and `NOW` with a moving average of the diff (in days) between the 2 dates. 
The moving avg should look 6 months back. 
Is it more clear now? Sorry for my poor explanation